# Authorization .NET 7 - Minimal API. Jwt token not valid, but everything is connected correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

I do not understand what the problem is, this is not the first time I write web applications, but I encountered this in the first, I seem to have connected everything correctly, I will attach the screens from below, but when requesting the method - where authorization is required, throws a 401 error, I always connected JWT like that, but this time something went wrong.

[POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjfEN.png)

[This is how the JWT setup looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRe3k.png)

[Continue - This is how the JWT setup looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSLYJ.png)

[This is what creating a JWT looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajbpo.png)

[Continue - This is what creating a JWT looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK8Y3.png)

**.NET 7 **

Assistance in resolving an error related to authorization.